# How do I convert Express query parameters back into a string?

Tags: string, express

Express is great with `req.query` and creating an object of the query parameters. In this case, I just want those query parameters as a string. This is how I did it:

```js
router.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  const { originalUrl } = req;
  console.log(originalUrl.slice(originalUrl.indexOf('?')));
```

But, I was wondering if there was a more direct or declarative way to do this. Surely this is not too uncommon of a task?

Answer (score 2):

`new URL("s://" + req.url).search` gives you the query parameters, including the leading `?`.

Comment: . That is a bit better. Why `s`, as in specifically the letter "s". Just random?

Comment: Yes, `s:` is a random URL scheme. I could have used `http:`.